# Как добавить поля в пользовательский тип записи?

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо создать пользовательский тип записи. Планирую, что одна запись этого типа будет как набор из вопросов и ответов к ним.
Вопрос: как в WordPress создать пользовательский тип записи, чтобы можно было добавлять поля прямо в записи прямо в админке? То есть добавлять как само поле с вопросом, так и поля с ответами к каждому вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте себе плагин advanced custom fields. Зарегистрируйте custom post types в описании будете писать вопрос, а с помощью acf создадите дополнительные поля для ответов и будете их выводить в цикле. Я думаю сделал бы именно так

Answer (score 0):

> как в wordpress создать пользовательский тип записи, чтобы можно было
>   добавлять поля прямо в записи прямо в админке?

Матчасть: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_post_types#Custom_Post_Types и https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

На практике: плагины, которые умеют это создавать. Напр [WCK](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/), [Types](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/types/) и множество других.